# JSON file extension in android

Tags: android, json, parsing

A little bit confusion regarding the format of JSON

Many tutorial sites explaining about JSON in android with the URL by the extension .json but some sites explained without the .json extension like

[Androidhive example](http://api.androidhive.info/contacts/)

i am confused to point out my json file in my project whether to make .json or without .json also possible? i created a json file with extension of xyz.com/xyz_json.php

is i am doing a wrong format?

Comment: nope. You are doing perfect. You just have to give the url where json is stored to parse the data.

Comment: File extentions mean nothing.  A file is data.  If you treat it as JSON data, you can name it with a .mp3 extention for all the OS cares.

Comment: Wellcome. Enjoy coding!!! @Brendon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 99% of the library or tools you will use in Android for JSON, the extension is not important. As [Avijit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2094399/avijit) said, you just have to refer the file with the good URL (however the extension). 
This is most of the time the same thing in other Linux based systems.

Answer (score 1):

As per my experience of JSON parsing we don't need the .json extension for such files. In some of my projects I have accessed the JSON from .txt files or from only string or directly from the URL. It depends on your's specific scenario.